# workaround for SPLIT 1000 file limit?

Tags: perl, unix, awk, sed

I need to split a few large files into specifically sized smaller files, with 500-5000 smaller files output. I'm using `split` with a -b designation, so I'm using a manual workaround when reaching the `split` 1000 file limit. Is there a another UNIX command or Perl one-liner that will accomplish this?

Comment: Can you adjust your file handles limit?

Comment: The `split` from GNU Coreutils has no such documented limit. You have to adjust the suffix length if you have a large number of files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure about the 1000 file limit?

The original `split` had no such limit, and there's no limit for GNU or BSD version of `split`. Maybe you're confusing the suffix length with some sort of limit. On BSD, the suffix starts at `.aaa` and goes all of the way to `.zzz` which is over 17,000 files.

You can use the `-a` flag to adjust the suffix size if the three character suffix isn't enough.

```
$ split -a 5 $file
```

Answer (score 4):

If I try to create lots of files, I get

```
$ perl -e'print "x"x5000' | split -b 1 && echo done.
split: output file suffixes exhausted
```

By default, the suffix length is two, which allows for 26<sup>2</sup> = 676 parts. Increasing it to three allows for 26<sup>3</sup> = 17,576 parts

```
$ perl -e'print "x"x5000' | split -b 1 -a 3 && echo done.
done.
```

Comment: (`perl -e'print "x"x5000'` creates file consisting of 5,000 `x` characters.)

Answer (score 1):

One can control Perl's notion of an input record by setting [`$/`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html):

> Setting `$/` to a reference to an integer, scalar containing an integer,
>   or scalar that's convertible to an integer will attempt to read
>   records instead of lines, with the maximum record size being the
>   referenced integer number of characters. So this:
>
> ```
> local $/ = \32768; # or \"32768", or \$var_containing_32768
> open my $fh, "<", $myfile or die $!;
> local $_ = <$fh>;
> ```
>
> will read a record of no more than 32768 characters from `$fh`.

---

So to split a large file into smaller files no larger than 1024 bytes, one could use the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

$/ = \1024;
my $filename = 'A';

while (<>) {

    open my $fh, '>', ($filename++ . '.txt') or die $!;
    print $fh $_;
    close $fh or die $!;
}
```