# File splitting in UNIX

Tags: perl, unix, awk, sed

I have a UNIX dataset with record length n (this will be changeable but will be always divisible exactly by 2769).

I want to process this file to end up with a new dataset with separate records of length 2769 and it needs to be done in UNIX (perl?, sed?, awk? or whatever).

I can do this in a shell script using a loop but the time it takes is excessive.

I tried 'split' but it appears that there is a limit to the length you can specify.

Can anyone suggest an efficient answer please?

Thank you,

Bernie

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24268989/2088135

Answer (score 2):

You can use perl from command line,

```
perl -Mautodie -ne 'BEGIN{$/ = \2769} print {open $f, ">", ++$i; $f} $_' file
```

Comment: Thank you. This looks promising. Ideally I would like the output in one dataset with end of line characters at the end of each 2769 block and an end of file at the end so that I can use it as a normal UNIX dataset. Bernie.

Answer (score 1):

`split` will handle this with charm

```
$ split -l 2769 -d <(seq 1 30000) section
$ wc -l sec*                                                                                    
2769 section00
2769 section01
2769 section02
2769 section03
2769 section04
2769 section05
2769 section06
2769 section07
2769 section08
2769 section09
2310 section10
30000 total
```

`-l` for line size, `-d` for numeric suffix and last argument is the output file prefix.  You have to replace `<(seq ..)` with your input file.

Comment: I think that the key to using `split` is to define the length of the suffix using the `-a` switch, as mentioned in the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that `split` isn't capable of doing this but one alternative would be to use awk:

```
awk 'NR%2769==1{ close(outfile); outfile = sprintf("%s%03d", FILENAME, ++i) }{ print > outfile }' file
```

This prints each line of the input file to the file whose name is composed of the input file, followed by a zero-padded 3 digit number. The number will increase by 1 every 2769 lines.

The call to `close` (which won't do anything the first time it is called), is useful if there are many output files, as otherwise they will all be left open by awk.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{print > ( FILENAME "." int( ( NR + 2768) / 2769) )}' YourFile
```

files name starting at *YourFile*.1